# Why is my javascript script not outputing?

Tags: javascript, html

EDIT: I'm still learning javascript, that's why there are so many simple mistakes.

I'm trying to make an online calculator for a friend's company, it has 2 types of employees and he needs to choose which one it is enter the money that they made and then the script makes the calculations.

For some reason my script isn't outputting anything, what am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>
<TITLE>Sum</TITLE>
<style>
    input,
    label {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
      function sum()
      {

         var num1 = document.myform.ordenado.value;
         var num2 = document.myform.valor.value;

        if(ordenado=tipo1){
            if(valor>650){
                var res= parseFloat(valor) * parseFloat(0.45);
            }else{
                var res= parseFloat(valor) * parseFloat(0.4);
            }
        }else{
            if(valor>650){
                var res= parseFloat(valor) * parseFloat(0.45);
            }else if(valor<500){
                var res= parseFloat(valor) * parseFloat(0.35);
            }else{
                var res= parseFloat(valor) * parseFloat(0.4);
            }
        }

         document.getElementById('add').value = res;
      }
    </script>

<h2>Ordenados</h2>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<FORM NAME="myform">
    <div style="float:left;margin-right:20px;">
        <label for="ordenado">Tipo de empregado</label>
        <select name="ordenado" id="ordenado">
                    <option value="tipo1">40% - 45%</option>
                    <option value="tipo2">35% - 40% - 45%</option>
                </select>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;margin-right:20px;">
        <label for="valor">Valor Semanal</label>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="valor" ID="valor" VALUE="" />
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;margin-right:20px;">
        <label for="button">&nbsp;</label>
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="=" onClick="sum()" />
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;margin-right:20px;">
        <label for="result">Resultado</label>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" ID="add" NAME="result" VALUE="" />
    </div>
</FORM>

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: because there is no `ordenado` & `tipo1` defined in your js

Comment: Note that `ordenado=tipo1` is an assignment, not a comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a few mistakes, here's the fix

```js
      function sum()
      {

         var num1 = document.myform.ordenado.value;
         var valor = parseFloat(document.myform.valor.value);
        if(num1=='tipo1'){
            if(valor>650){
                var res= valor * parseFloat(0.45);
            }else{
                var res= valor * parseFloat(0.4);
            }
        }else{
            if(valor>650){
                var res= valor * parseFloat(0.45);
            }else if(valor<500){
                var res= valor * parseFloat(0.35);
            }else{
                var res= valor * parseFloat(0.4);
            }
        }

         document.getElementById('add').value = res;
      }
```

```css
    input,
    label {
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<HTML>

<HEAD>
<TITLE>Sum</TITLE>
<h2>Ordenados</h2>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<FORM NAME="myform">
    <div style="float:left;margin-right:20px;">
        <label for="ordenado">Tipo de empregado</label>
        <select name="ordenado" id="ordenado">
                    <option value="tipo1">40% - 45%</option>
                    <option value="tipo2">35% - 40% - 45%</option>
                </select>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;margin-right:20px;">
        <label for="valor">Valor Semanal</label>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="valor" ID="valor" VALUE="" />
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;margin-right:20px;">
        <label for="button">&nbsp;</label>
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="=" onClick="sum()" />
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;margin-right:20px;">
        <label for="result">Resultado</label>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" ID="add" NAME="result" VALUE="" />
    </div>
</FORM>

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Missing quotes, ordenado undefined, tipo1 and value reference errors, and num2 not used.

The main issue from a "comprehension" point of view was you trying to assign a variable in a if statement.

```
if(ordenado=tipo1) // the = operator is used for assignment, not comparison
```

To compare variables, you need to use comparison operators, == (without type checking), or === (type checking). I recommend you go through [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators) to learn more.

Apart from that, be careful how you name your variables, don't call a var `num1`, then later try to use it by calling `ordenado`.

I ordered it all, but a quick look at your console would have enabled you to do the same. Good Luck !

Comment: @IgorSílva no problems, but you should compare with your question and see what you did wrong. Nothing difficult to understand but you need to get familiar with the basic concepts of variable naming and comparison/assignment

Comment: Thank you! It now works wonders, I'm still learning javascript that's why there are so many newbie mistakes, also i don't have a console, I'm writing the code in VS Code @xShirase

Comment: You need a console!! https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging

Comment: @xShirase Well thanks again, I was so caught up in writing code I forgot the capabilities of VS Code,

Comment: hahaha, you'll soon move from VSCode for Javascript, in the meantime don't give up, and remember SO has all the answers, and can point you to very important resources! Please accept the answer if it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You never defined the variables `ordenado` and `tipo1`. You can do this with

```
var ordenado="your value";
```

`if (ordenado=tipo1)` is not the `if` you want. In this case, you are simply stating that `ordenado` (which is undefined) is equal to `tipo1` which is also undefined. Instead, you need to change it to

```
if (ordenado==tipo1)
```

or

```
if (ordenado=="tipo1")
```

if `"tipo1"` is a string.

Comment: there's more, keep digging :p